# How to add keyboard layout in dwm

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, display, dwm, mx-linux

I want to add additional language input to my linux. I am using MX Linux and DWM desktop environment. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MX Linux is Debian based, you can set your keyboard layout using,
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.
The keyboard settings file is `/etc/default/keyboard` if you prefer to do it manually. You can set the layout, the available languages, variants and the key combination to switch layout/language. In Debian the settings in this file are respected by console and Xorg.

Second part, is how to view the selected language in dwm bar. There are many ways, I'll suggest you two:

- I suppose you've patched DWM with systray patch. If not I suggest you to do it, many apps use the system tray. In that case you can `apt install fbxkb`. It's a light app which shows an icon-flag on the system tray of the selected language. Easy and nice, but I don't like the flag on the systray :)
- Use some dwm status bar customization. There are many available in [dwm status monitor page](http://dwm.suckless.org/status_monitor/). Most support showing current keyboard layout; I use dwm-bar. More steps to setup than the first proposal, but it's helpful to have whatever info you like on the bar - since you can add much more than just the current keyboard layout.

Comment: Wow, thank you for that explanation. I'll try these steps